# zooming a selected area of google visualization chart

Tags: google-visualization, visualization

I am working on Google-visualization chart. I would like that when i select particular area of chart i can zoom that particular selected area. I would also like it to do the same with line chart, bar chart, pie chart

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
          google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
          function drawChart() {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Company1');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Company2');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Company3');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Company4');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Company5');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Company6');
            data.addRows([
              ['Feb 1, 2012 - Feb 28, 2012', 10, 10, 5, 15, 10, 55]
            ]);
            data.addRows([
              ['Mar 1, 2012 - Mar 31, 2012', 10, 10, 5, 15, 10, 55]
            ]);
            var options = {
              title: 'Total Reviews',
              hAxis: {title: '',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'blue'}}
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('total'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
            google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function() {
              var selection = chart.getSelection()[0];
              var label = data.getColumnLabel(selection.column);
              // alert(label); //SOMETHING GOES HERE TO MAKE IT ZOOOM
            })
          }      
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="total" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by, "zoom". Can you elaborate?

Comment: When i select particular area of chart it will make zoom that area.

Comment: Okay, for a pie chart, what does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, and looking through the config options, you should be able to use an option called `explorer`

```
// before you pass the options to the drawing function
options.explorer = {
  actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset']
  /* you can add more options */
}
```

Please take a look at the `explorer` and other options in [the line chart API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options) and read the notes

> Note: The explorer only works with continuous axes (such as numbers or dates).

So your example domain column data must be transformed into actual `Date` objects, and your first column should be defined as

```
data.addColumn('date','Date');
```

or my preferred way

```
data.addColumn({role:'domain', type:'date', label:'Date'});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do this you have to use `explorer.actions` . In Google Area chart

```
The Google Charts explorer supports three actions
```

`dragToPan:` Drag to pan around the chart horizontally and vertically. 
To pan only along the horizontal axis, use `explorer: { axis: 'horizontal' }`. Similarly for the vertical axis.

`dragToZoom:` The explorer's default behavior is to zoom in and out when the user scrolls. If `explorer: { actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'] }` is used, dragging across a rectangular area zooms into that area. Google recommend using `rightClickToReset` whenever `dragToZoom` is used. See

```
explorer.maxZoomIn, explorer.maxZoomOut, and explorer.zoomDelta for zoom customizations.
```

`rightClickToReset:` Right clicking on the chart returns it to the original pan and zoom level

More details [Google Area Chart Customize](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart)